# I am getting an assertion error and i don't know why

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random

class game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.hp = random.randint(1,20)
        self.dmg = random.randint(1,15)
        self.regn = random.randint(1,3)

        self.stab = 3-self.hp
    def player(self):
        print("Health")
        print(self.hp)
        print("Damage")
        print(self.dmg)
        print("Regen")
        print(self.regn)

    def Mob_1(self):
       hit = self.hp - 3

       if 1 == 1 :
           print("you were hit")
           hit

       self.mob1_hp=8
       self.mob1_dmg=4
       while self.mob1_hp <= 0:
            hit
            self.mob1_hp -= self.dmg
       print(self.mob1_hp)

    goblin = Mob_1('self')


    def day_1(self,goblin):
        print("\nIt day one")
        goblin
```

The first function works fine `player(self)`, but I am getting an assertion error when trying to do the other one. To explain why I made goblin it is so I can call the whole function at once(or that was what it is made to do). The error in particular is form the `hit = self.hp - 3` line of code. For more clarification here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 3, in <module>
    class game:
  line 33, in game
    goblin = Mob_1('self')
line 20, in Mob_1
    hit = self.hp - 3
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'hp'
```

ps I am very new to this website I have looked at questions in the past for help but I can't seem to find a way to fix it

Comment: An `AttributeError` is a different thing than an `AssertionError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `goblin = Mob_1('self')` doesn't make any sense. You're calling a method of your `game` object directly within its body, but passing the string `'self'` instead of an instance the `game` class. That's going to break all kinds of things.

I'm not exactly sure how to fix it, since your code doesn't make a whole lot of sense, and I don't really know what you're trying to do. Perhaps you'd be able to get closer to what you want if you renamed some of the things you're creating and reorganized them. Currently you're trying to do a bunch of things in the `game` class that don't really seem appropriate there. For instance, you're tracking two sets of `hp` stats, which seem more like stats of the characters that are fighting than stats of the game itself.

So instead of a `game` class, I suggest you create a `Creature` class that keeps track of the stats for one creature (either the player, or an enemy):

```
class Creature:
    def __init__(self, name, hp, damage, regen):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.damage = damage
        self.regen = regen

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} (Health: {}, Damage: {}, Regen: {})".format(self.name, self.hp,
                                                               self.dmg, self.regen)
```

The player and monsters will be instance of that class (or maybe instance of subclasses, if you need to be able to customize them more). You can write a function to make two of them fight against each other:

```
def fight(creature1, creature2):
    while creature1.hp > 0 and createure2.hp > 0:
        creature1.hp -= creature2.damage
        creature2.hp -= creature1.damage
        # do something with regen here?
        # report on damage?

    if creature1.hp < 0 and creature2.hp < 0:
        print("Both {} and {} have died".format(creature1.name, creature2.name))
    else:
        print("{} has died".format((creature1 if creature1.hp < 0
                                    else creature2).name.capitalize())
```

Call it like this:

```
player = Creature("the player",
                  random.randint(1,20),
                  random.randint(1,15),
                  random.randint(1,3))
goblin = Creature("the goblin", 8, 4, 0)

print("Battle between {} and {}:".format(player, goblin)) # uses __str__

fight(player, goblin)
```